# How to select double leg kickstand

Tags: kickstand

I have to park my bicycle, leaning it against a low metal fence. Unfortunately the frame of the bike gets scratched. Though I try to protect it by wrapping it with polyethylene, some parts are still unprotected. So, I decided to buy a double leg kickstand: to keep the bike standing straight, so it won't touch the fence.

I found out, that there are cheap and expensive kickstands:

1. [1-st kickstand](http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-MASSLOAD-Double-Leg-Kickstand-For-24-28-Rim-Black-/141042540143?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_3&hash=item20d6ca5e6f) costs 99 GBP
2. [2-nd kickstand](http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-MASSLOAD-Double-Leg-Kickstand-For-24-28-Rim-Silver-/400556672089?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_15&hash=item5d4309c459) costs 43,52 AUD
3. [3-rd kickstand](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Bike-Bicycle-Middle-Install-Double-Leg-Kickstand-Alloy-Reparing-Parking-Stand-/400701187069?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_15&hash=item5d4ba6e3fd) costs 21,99 AUD

What is so special in the 1-st and 2-nd kickstands, that makes the price so high? The 3-rd seems ok to me.

Comment: Given that it is ebay, it probably has more to do with local market forces.  It is odd though since both are by the same seller, just different countries.  The silver one (first) is closer to the retail price that is listed on US Amazon site and converting to USD.  Now, an issue I have with these stands is that they don't let the bike frame get close to a lockable object.  You will find times when it wont work.  They are still great for loading panniers, trailers, and just hanging out in the open.

Comment: @BPugh I have a kickstand similar to these and I've never had a problem getting right up next to a bike rack, telephone pole, whatever. If anything, I find it even easier than a traditional kickstand because the bike stands straight up and doesn't lean away from the object in question.

Comment: @jimirings, I find lots of things that work as well myself, and fully recommend these types of stands.  I was thinking wall like objects like a tall chainlink fence pose problems for myself.  I also have a short shackle lock which complicates it.

Comment: @BPugh I find that the handlebars are a bigger hindrance to stuff like that. I do have a longer, cable lock though. So that probably helps.

Comment: I have a double kickstand (similar to link 1 but cheaper) and like it, especially with the baby seat fitted (too top heavy while strapping the baby in for a normal kickstand).  The bike has blown over on the kickstand, and is tips over easily if knocked it e.g. with another bike.  I also find that even on the slightest slope you have to make the bike  face up (or down) hill for it to not just fall over.  Some models may allow you to trim the legs down to fix this; on mine the feet don't come off.

Comment: @ChrisH What sort of kickstand is yours? Can you show on ebay?

Comment: Consider the kick stand itself counld damage the bike  http://surlybikes.com/info_hole/spew/kickstands_on_long_haul_truckers

Comment: @user4035, it's not on ebay, but this is the one, or a slightly newer version, on [dutchbikebits](http://www.dutchbikebits.com/hebie-0605-double-stand?keyword=stand&category_id=48)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the Velo-Orange double-leg, folding [Copenhagen](http://store.velo-orange.com/index.php/accessories/chainguards-stay-protectors-kickstands/vo-retractable-dual-leg-kickstand.html) kickstand. The folding styles are much better compared with rigid style (aka, motorcycle) kickstands in that they fold out of the way rather than at risk of being hit by your ankle or the cranks.

I bought a cheap pair of folding kickstands and disprefer them to the VOs. The problem with the cheap one was that the plastic "boots" on them fell off easily as they were not tightly fitted or easily secured with an allen screw.  The spring is also not as strong and the manufacturing tolerances greater so it "clunked" a lot when I rode over bumps.

But it looks like you're in <strike>Australia</strike> Russia so the VO may not be available to you. Still, I'd ask at your local bike store if they have a high quality version similar to the VO. The VO is US$33 so this gives you a sense of how much you should pay for good kickstand -- but be aware that some unscrupulous ebay vendors will charge ridiculous amounts of money for cheap merchandise in the hopes of catching a rube.